# Relationship between distributions.

Tags: probability-distributions, correlation

I have three different variables. I can obtain distributions for the variables from a common set of data. I am not seeing any obvious direct correlation/relationship between the variables. Can I infer anything from the three variable distributions? One is johnson, one is Pareto and the third gamma. I tried dividing the data set up into sections but the distribution parameters all came out the same ( Well I still need to double check that I processed correctly). Would the fact that they have different distributions rule out any correlation/relationship and if so is there any mathematical proof for such a conclusion.

Thanks

Adding image of distributions[Image of Distributions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oo9Pq.jpg)

Comment: This question seems a bit off-topic. Maybe try crossvalidated stack exchange.

Also, your question is not very clear anyway. Do you have a data set and you are trying to fit three different distributions? Or you have three different data sets of (arguably) independent observations? Or you have a data set of multivariated (3-dimensional) observations? All these hypothesis will obviously affect any inference you are trying to make.

Comment: Just a comment on terminology..  your distributions are likely "FIT" by pareto, johnson, and gamma unless you have any underlying physical reason these distributions ARE those things. Correlation is not equality. It seems you probably want something like pearson or spearman correlation analysis here. But this is an inferential statistics question, not a math question, as another commenter pointed out.

Comment: Data is Astronomic data. I have a survey which has a measure of redness uminusr, A distance to 5 nearest neighbours DistanceTo5nn and CountInCyl number of local galaxies within a certain size. I am trying to establish if there is a relationship between uminusr and either of the other two variables. Having tried to look for a direct correlation and not found one I have used scipy to fit distributions and uminusr is johnson, CountInCyl is Pareto and DistanceTo5nn is gamma.

Comment: A standard approach for homoscedastic / approximately normally-distributed data would be pearson's correlation analysis on the paired variables you hypothesize a relationship between. You can attempt to transform the data to attain homoscedastic / normally-distributed characteristics to apply this technique. Otherwise there are other more versatile techniques available. But... crossvalidated. Testing for correlations between regressed distributions is not an accepted way to infer correlations on data as far as I am aware.

Comment: "approximately normally-distributed data" the johnson distribution has a very obvious bulge higher than the mean and the gamma is fat before the mean, would they count as approximately normal as they both look none regular normal to me.

Comment: Have added image of distributions to original question.

Comment: Eh they're just pretty standard looking low-confidence empirical fits, in all cases. I wouldn't read to much into what distribution "looks best" when regressed to data. Maybe there are physical arguments for what distributions should be satisfied by the data? Those you can trust. Anyway.. if you want to test for correlations you need to conduct correlation analysis. Approximate normality is typically assessed with Q-Q plots. I would suggest to find the standard practice in astrophysics journals to infer correlations and then copy it. Inferential stats is more tradition than it is rigor imo